# When scraping a betting site (Pinnacle.com), I'm unable to retrieve data

Tags: selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape player prop lines for NBA off of
https://www.pinnacle.com/en/basketball/nba/matchups/#period:0:spread, which requires me to first retrieve the links for the individual games.

For some reason, the following program works on other sites (such as Draftkings), but doesn't return anything for Pinnacle. I tried using `Selenium` and `Pandas`, but nothing seemed to work. I'm a new coder so I would appreciate any help. Does anyone know why or have a fix?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
 
url = 'https://www.pinnacle.com/en/basketball/nba/matchups/#period:0:spread'
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
 
urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Almost certainly the page content that you want is populated by AJAX calls, so is not present in the basic page retrieved from the URL.

Comment: You may use a library like https://github.com/apify/crawlee to fetch and parse dynamic content easily. I found this library very useful after trying many other scraping libs

Answer (score 1):

Because of tagging with `selenium` here is an example, that gets the game links:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.pinnacle.com/en/basketball/nba/matchups/#period:0:spread')

for e in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a:has(div[class*="style_matchupMetadata"])'):
    print(e.get_attribute('href'))
```